# After Upgrading Matrix 2.4.3 → 2.5.3 P&T Dropdown Fields Fail in Templates

Tags: matrix

After upgrading from Matrix 2.4.3 to 2.5.3 on EE 2.5.5, P&T Dropdowns (1.0.3) used within Matrix fields are no longer parsing in templates. They simply return nothing.

Nothing looks out of place in the CP following the upgrade and I'm not receiving any errors. I haven't touched my template code.

I've tried removing a matrix row from one of my Channel Entries, saving it empty and then re-inputing the value with no luck.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

After further debugging the issue actually doesn't have anything to do with *P&T Dropdown*, but rather the use of a `var_prefix` name in a template that was identical to the Matrix field *short name*.

In Matrix 2.4.3 this didn't appear to be a problem (although I have now come to question why I had originally used a `var_prefix` as it was unnecessary). In 2.5.3 this causes the template to stop processing when it encounters the Matrix field and doesn't report any errors.

Example of what **NOT** to do:

```
{matrix var_prefix="matrix"}
    {matrix:name}
{/matrix}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try upgrading to the latest version of [P&T Field Pack on github](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/pt_field_pack) (version 1.1). I tried it out and this version of P&T Dropdowns works on EE 2.5.5 for me. If that still doesn't work on your install, please post your field settings and template code.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on version 1.1. My issue was actually the result of a `var_prefix` name identical to the matrix fields short name. Nonetheless I have update P&T Field Pack.